# R extracting array from list

Tags: arrays, r, list, extract

I need help with extracting array from list.

```
array1 <- array(c(1,2,3), dim = c(3,3,3))
array2 <- array(c(10,20,30), dim = c(3,3,3))
A <- list(array1,array2)
B <- A[1]
```

"A" is list of two arrays. When I want to extract for example first array and assign it to "B", B isn't array, but it is also list. How can I access data stored in B? B[1,1,1] doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[` to extract element in a list. If you use `[`, the output would still be a list.

```
array1 <- array(c(1,2,3), dim = c(3,3,3))
array2 <- array(c(10,20,30), dim = c(3,3,3))
A <- list(array1,array2)
B <- A[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are using `magrittr`, then `extract2` can be used for the same purpose

```
library(magrittr)
B <- A %>% 
       extract2(1)
```